# Finding an integral's max and min

Tags: calculus, integration, optimization, definite-integrals

I've been asked to find the max and min of the following:

$F(x)=\displaystyle\int_0^{2x-x^2}\!\cos\dfrac{1}{1+t^2}\mathrm{d}t$

I tried applying the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (taking the derivative of both sides).

After that, it would make sense to me for me to look for when the right side is equal to zero as that would indicate a critical point of $F(x)$ but I can't quite nail it down.

I feel like I'm pretty much stuck here:

$F'(x)=\cos \frac{1}{1+(2x-x^2)^2} * \frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{1+(2x-x^2)^2}$

I have noticed that $2x-x^2$ has a maximum of 1 and no minimum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(t) = \cos (1+t^2)^{-1}$.  Then note that $f(t) > 0$ on $t \in [0,\infty)$ and is a monotonically increasing function on this same interval, since $$f'(t) = \frac{2t \sin (1+t^2)^{-1}}{(1+t^2)^2} \ge 0$$ for all $t \ge 0$.  Therefore, the integral $$F(x) = \int_{t=0}^{2x-x^2} f(t) \, dt$$ achieves its greatest value when $2x-x^2$ is maximized.

Formally, we can find the derivative of $F$ with respect to $x$ using the fundamental theorem and the chain rule:  $$F'(x) = 2(1-x)f(2x-x^2),$$ and again, because $f(t) > 0$ for $t \in [0, \infty)$ we conclude that the critical point of $F$ is $x = 1$, yielding a maximum.

Comment: The answer key has that there is no minimum value.

Comment: @Yeah.. Indeed, you are right.  If $x> 2$ or $x < 0$, some interesting behavior occurs in $F(x)$.

Comment: How would one go about showing that? It seems to me that if $x=0$ or $x=2$ then it's just an integral from 0 to 0 which would appear to minimize it.

Comment: @Yeah..  It is possible for the value of the integral to be negative, since for sufficiently large $x$, $2x - x^2 < 0$ and $F(x) = -\int_{t=0}^{-(2x-x^2)} f(t) \, dt$.  As $\lim_{t \to \infty} f(t) = 1$, it follows that $F(x) < 0$ when $x$ is "very large" or "very small."

Comment: What does that mean though?

Comment: Any thoughts on the minimum?